# Using a Qt GUI created by Qt Designer in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, user-interface, qt-designer

i'm completely new to Qt but i managed to get some simple windows and frames to work. I'm running Eclipse on a 64 bit Kubuntu system. After editing my code in Eclipse, im running qmake and make from command line.

Yesterday i gave a try to Qt Designer, which works fine for me, compared to "hard-code" the widgets and buttons in eclipse.
However, i won't switch to QT Creator because i'm very used to Eclipse.

My goal is to create the GUI in Qt Designer and use the generated code in Eclipse.

Running qmake -project, qmake and make generates a header file for my Mainwindow, containing the class code.

But when i try to include this header file in my Eclipse code, make stops with an error because g++ can't find the header file (seems the header has not been created yet).

I have to admit, im still confused about the Qt building process.
So, how could i manage to design my GUI via Qt Designer and still use Eclipse as my coding IDE?

Greetings,
lugge

Edit:
 My Eclipse Project is a "Empty Makefile Project". As far as i know, this means i have to take care of the whole build process.  Eclipse wont do anything for me.

I have not tried running "make" from Eclipse because the Makefile has to be generated by qmake. Thus, after eiting and saving my code in Eclipse i run qmake and make from command line.

Qmake senses there is a .ui file and generates the header file for this class.
Problem is if i try to include this header in Eclipse, my source code file can't be compiled.

For me it seems thats when "make" invokes g++ with my source code file, the header of the GUI has not been created.

So why am I doing it this way?
Well, I don't want to be addicted to a IDE like Qt Creator or stuff. Because that means, everony trying to compile my project needs meta-informations such as a config-file or project-specific settings for that specific IDE.

In my C-projects i use a handwritten Makefile, so you just need to have GCC installed (which you usually have) and type "make".

I'm trying to get as close as possible to this with Qt-projects.

Comment: Try this: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-eclipse/

Comment: Does qmake/make called from the command line build properly? How did you setup your Eclipse project? You can setup the Eclipse project so that Eclipse simply calls `make`, so that there is no difference between calling make from the command line or executing the build command from within Eclipse. Does the error actually happen during build, or is it an error from the Eclipse CDT indexer which can not find the include file while editing the code?

Comment: Can you confirm the `uic` being ran before `make`?  Otherwise your `.ui` files will not have code generated for them.

Comment: I've edited my first posting, trying to provide this informations. I guess cmannett85 is mentioning my problem. I can't confirm that because, as i said, the makefile was generated by qmake.

Comment: "Qmake senses there is a .ui file and generates the header file for this class", "when "make" invokes g++ with my source code file, the header of the GUI has not been created." - which is it?  After you run `qmake` is the generated header file there or not?

Answer (score 1):

You need 4 things :

- The .ui generated by Qt Designer

=> about.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
<class>About</class>
<widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
<property name="geometry">
<rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
</rect>
</property>
<property name="windowTitle">
<string>A Propos</string>
</property>
</widget>
<layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
<resources/>
<connections/>
</ui>
```

- The cpp / h associated with the .ui, for example this :

An about Window (about.cpp) =>

```
#include "about.h"
#include "ui_about.h"

About::About(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::About)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

About::~About()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

(about.h) =>

```
#ifndef ABOUT_H
#define ABOUT_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
    class About;
}

class About : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit About(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~About();

private:
    Ui::About *ui;
};

#endif // ABOUT_H
```

In the .pro file

```
SOURCES += about.cpp
HEADERS += about.h
FORMS   += about.ui
```

Comment: Thanks, i will give this a try when i'm at home. Does this mean i have to write the .pro file by hand? In the guides i've read so far they use "qmake -project" for creating the .pro file.

Comment: I've tried your example, but running "make" throws this error: about.cc: In constructor ‘About::About(QWidget*)’:                                                                  
about.cc:4:61: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Ui::About’
about.h:7:11: error: forward declaration of ‘struct Ui::About’

Comment: Your .ui must be wrong, you must set the class Name used by the .ui file with "<class>About</class>"

Comment: You're right, thank you. I created the .ui file yesterday, forgetting about the class name. But i got one error left: About.cc: In constructor ‘About::About(QWidget*)’:
about.cc:6:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘Ui::About::setupUi(About* const)’
about.cc:6:21: note: candidate is:
ui_about.h:38:10: note: void Ui_About::setupUi(QMainWindow*)
ui_about.h:38:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘About* const’ to ‘QMainWindow*’
make: *** [about.o] Error 1

Comment: Ui file or About class are wrong.
In my example About extends QDialog and not QMainWindow...

Comment: Finally, i managed to get it working. After i changed your example to fit for QMainWindow i needed another source file containing the main-function, which contains a QApplication and an object of type "About". So i wonder, is this a "good" coding style? I create the ui-file for each widget or form and a .cc and .h file for each ui, containing the con/destructors, setting signals and slots and stuff. The "logic" is placed in another "main"-file(s). Is there a not-to-big open source example with "good" code for studying?